# Short story, 50`s or early 60`s, Alien starship arrives speaking obsolete commercial cable code

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a Sci-Fi short story, 1950s or early 60s. Alien starship arrives but communicates only in an obsolete commercial telegraph code.  A translator finds the code and asks to be taken aboard the alien ship. Key words from the translator (as I remember) were something like BEROM BODAT VEMAN WEGOT. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The story in question is "[Berom](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56071)" by John Berryman, originally published in Astounding Science Fiction in 1951.

I've found a [brief description](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/linguistics) that seems to tally nicely;

> "John Berryman's "Berom" has an amusing
> variant on the theme, in which incomprehensible visiting aliens turn
> out to be speaking in a UK commercial cable code of the 1920s that
> they have picked up by radio"

The original [code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_code_%28communications%29) in the story was "**BEROM BODAD VEMAN WEGOT**"

[image: Berom story]